# How to change wallpaper programmatically in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ios10, iphone-privateapi

I use the privite API to change wallpapper. It works well in iOS 9.3, but in iOS 10 nothing happend, no crash.

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"PLStaticWallpaperImageViewController");
_wallPaper = [[class alloc] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"initWithUIImage:") withObject:_image];
int wallpaperMode = 0;
[_wallPaper setValue:@(wallpaperMode) forKey:@"wallpaperMode"];
[_wallPaper setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"allowsEditing"];
[_wallPaper  setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"saveWallpaperData"]; //
NSString *selector = @"setImageAsLockScreenClicked:";
[_wallPaper performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(selector) withObject:nil];
```

Does anyone know how to do this in iOS 10?